# How to retrieve output variable from Firebird

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, firebird, lazarus, freepascal

I have a free pascal application using Firebird. How can I retrieve the output variable from this Firebird stored procedure:

```
input parameters: ID (integer)
output parameters: G (integer)

begin
 if(select town.count from town where town.id=:id) then
    G = 100
 else
    G = 200;
  suspend;
end

in designer->SQL 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE ID_DEV :ID RETURNING_VALUES :G
```

In code:

```
SQLQueryProc.Prepare; //here i got an error
SQLQueryProc.ParamByName('ID').Value:=res;
SQLQueryProc.ExecSQL();
SQLTransaction.CommitRetaining;
ID:=SQLQueryProc.FieldByName('G').AsInteger;
```

When I run my app I get an error:

> Token unknown line (where :G located)

I have tried many combinations. What is the reason?

Answer (score 1):

The `RETURNING_VALUES :G` clause is only valid Firebird syntax inside PSQL (so inside a stored procedure). If you want to execute the stored procedure, you should only use:

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE ID_DEV :ID
```

As you want to have an executable stored procedure, you should also remove the `SUSPEND` from your stored procedure, as having a suspend-statement inside your stored procedure makes it a selectable stored procedure instead.